# Activiti: dynamically setting candidate group of a user task

Tags: activiti

In my process definition, I have following flow:

> start-event -> userTaskA -> userTaskB -> end-event

I want to set candidate group for userTaskB based on the user who completed userTaskA.

For delegate task, there is a method available 'addCandidateGroup'. But I couldn't find any such method for user task(via TaskService).

How can this be achieved?

PS: I am wrong here. TaskService does have method 'addCandidateGroup'.

Comment: So... your problem is solved by yourself?

Comment: Yes, it seems so.